# Van de Graaf Canon and title pages

Tags: page-layout, book, composition

I am currently working on typesetting a book and I have been fairly consistent about following the [Van de Graaf canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canons_of_page_construction#Van_de_Graaf_canon). However, the question arises when dealing with the front matter, whether it is ideal to remain consistent with the canon on the title page (which is likely going to contain artwork within the whole textframe) or whether to abandon it in favour of something a bit more centred.

Are there any stylistic discussions which address these concerns, or alternately, any illustrations of these usages in context?

Comment: This seems pretty broad and borderline opinion based... What are your concerns of both sides?

Comment: @ZachSaucier, I assume that there is literature which supports either position, although personally I'm weighing consistency vs. having the title centred, as either could lend a certain æsthetic which could be perceived either as off kilter or correct.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want to communicate, and what the book is for. However, I would say that extreme consistency in a grid application to a cover like this one has slight modernist undertones - the principle of "truth to materials/structure" comes to mind, where the structure of a design is revealed in a raw sort of way. Typically you see grids like these applied to front matter of typography theory books, with the connotation of communicating the idea of deconstructing the type itself? (a meta perspective towards the design, if you like).

Comment: @johnp, I have been fairly consistent, although the bottom margin changes based on content, so as to avoid widows and orphans and keep pagination of certain portions of the text consistent.

Comment: This isn't the Van de Graaf Cannon, but this kind of example comes to mind ![Explorations in Typography cover](http://typographica.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Explorations-in-Typography.jpg)

Consider the idea of using _type as image_ for the cover

Comment: @johnp, it's a great usage of type as image, but it wouldn't go with the content of my book, considering that it is a siddur

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt In which case a classical approach as in Yorik's answer would be more appropriate as far as communication goes. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The covers are always centered, but the interiors are typically consistent.

If there is a large amount of decoration, it is typically fully centered (with gutter adjustment) but with any "bookish" content still biased to be consistent.

[image: Keats book from Bonhams Auction]
[image: Title page designed by Frank Lloyd Wright]

Comment: Can you tell me the title of this beautiful book on John Keats?
Thanks!